# Ranorex vs Sikuli | Automating flash websites

Tags: flash, automation, ui-automation, sikuli, ranorex

Could you point me some pros and cons of using ranorex vs sikuli for flash based website automation?

Also it will be very helpful if any other tools widely used for testing flash based websites.

-Sudarson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you point me some pros and cons of using **ranorex vs sikuli** for flash based website automation?

Apples and oranges really but in saying so, both Ranorex and Sikuli can test Flash applications however the way both products go about it are quite different.

### Mechanism

As Sikuli states:

> It uses **image recognition** to identify and control GUI components. **It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code**.  [More...](http://www.sikuli.org/)

Ranorex on the other hand can discover individual screen elements; represent them by XPaths; and code-generate type-safe c# UI repository code.

### Abstraction

Ranorex test cases are more decoupled from the underlying screen technology and layout.  TC's refer to code-generated repository items rather than explicit screen references.

### Breakage with time

Sikuli is more likely to break when the UI layout changes; Ranorex not so much.

### Image Recognition

Both products support IR.   Sikuli only supports IR.

### Maintenance

As the AUT's screens evolve, so too the impact on tests involving around image recognition.

If a screen changes with Sikuli, you'll need to recapture the reference images.

In Ranorex we merely update a XPath.

### Conclusion

Image recognition have their place, in fact we use it for aspects of our DICOM imaging based products, however I'm not sure it is wise to invest in a purely-image based test solution for those TCs where image-based comparison is not absolutely necessary.